# Nissan Micra 2001 start up problem. Just screeching

Tags: electrical, starting, nissan

I find that in the morning when my car is cold and I try to start it. It doesn't make the turning over noise. It just screeches. I'm not sure how to describe it. 
Sorta like a belt or fan noise. 
I turn ignition off and it starts the second time. I have found it's getting more regular and I have to try 2 or 3 times before it properly turns over.
It's a Nissan Micra 2001
I don't know loads about cars but wondering if it's a common or easy-to-fix problem.
Thankyou

Comment: This may be the starter teeth or gear not engaging with the flywheel. This will need checking.